# Change size of cutplanes tool in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using ForgeViewer to display both IFC models and custom geometry (point clouds and meshes using THREE.js directly), and I'm using the Section tool to cut away parts of the model.

Is there anyway I can set the size of the planes in the UI. I want the arrows and planes to be centered around specific models making them easier to use. Also, it would be nice to be able to set the default size and position of the cutting box.

[image: here]

[image: here]

Answer (score 1):

The size of the cutting plane/box as well as the position of the manipulating gizmo are estimated by the section tool based on the bounding box of all visible objects. There's no UI to change that behavior, but you might be able to reverse engineer the official [Section](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/extensions/Section/Section.js) tool and perhaps modify it to your needs.

Edit: alternatively, you could retrieve the THREE.js geometry representing the cutting plane *after* it's been created by the Section tool (and placed into `viewer.impl.sceneAfter`) and customize it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Petr's answer...

1. Use the 'box section' tool (see screenshot) and manually adjust the box size by clicking on each of the box faces to adjust.
   [image]
2. Then use Augusto's blog post (below) to programmatically capture (using `viewer.getState();`) and replay your box section (`viewer.setCutPlanes(planes);`).

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-setcutplanes